# Collation with CSS print stylesheets?

Tags: css

I've written a app that, among other things, lets users export data in a print-friendly format. It does this by generating a HTML file that contains print-related CSS (e.g. the `@page` media query). The resulting exported file is pure HTML, CSS and Javascript, no fancy frameworks.

We've also got a printer at work that automatically staples jobs together. So if you print 10 copies of a document that has 3 pages, it'll print 3 pages, staple those together, then repeat.

The HTML file the app exports has about 1,500 records in it, grouped by a field (e.g. Username). I'm using the `page-break-before` CSS property to force a page break at the end of each grouped section of data, but I'm wondering if there's a way to tell the printer to "end" a document there and start a new one so it'll be stapled?

Basically splitting one file up into several individual "documents", while only sending one job to the printer.

I'm pretty sure there isn't, and the solution is to just print the whole document and manually separate and staple the documents together, which I'm happy to do and will no doubt end up doing, but now I'm curious if there's a way to do a "soft end" to a printed page, in the same way that you can force a page break using CSS.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to instruct the printer to staple a job together based on page breaks specified in the HTML/CSS of the exported file.

You might be able to achieve this with a generated PDF, or rather multiple PDF that you send at once to the printer.